# ¿Cómo encriptar un id en la URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy encriptando un "id" de la siguiente manera en la vista:

```
                    <!--------------------ENCRIPTAR---------------------->
                    @{ 
                        string encriptar() {
                            string id_origen = item.ID_Charla;
                            ClsEncripta Encrip = new ClsEncripta();
                            ClsEstadoRegistro Result = new ClsEstadoRegistro
                            {
                                Detalle = Encrip.Encriptar(id_origen)
                            };
                            Result.Detalle = Result.Detalle.Replace("/", "°");
                            Result.Detalle = Result.Detalle.Replace("+", "¬");

                            return Result.Detalle;
                        }
                    }
                    <!---------------------------------------------------->
                <div class="btn-incribirse d-flex flex-row">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Inscribirse", "CrearInteresado", new { id = encriptar() }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
```

Y cuando pasa por el controlador "CrearInteresado" ya se encripta pero despues de unos segundos me muestra el valor "id" (lo desencripta).

```
    //Crear Interesados
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(string id)
    {

        /*******DESENCRIPTAR*******/
        id = id.Replace("°", "/");
        id = id.Replace("¬", "+");

        ClsEncripta Encrip = new ClsEncripta();
        id = Encrip.Desencriptar(id);
        /**************************/

        .....

        return View(new ClsInteresado());
    }
```

Lo que he intentado hacer es volverlo a encriptar al final de mi metodo ActionResult

```
    //Crear Interesados
    public ActionResult CrearInteresado(string id)
    {

        /*******DESENCRIPTAR*******/
        id = id.Replace("°", "/");
        id = id.Replace("¬", "+");

        ClsEncripta Encrip = new ClsEncripta();
        id = Encrip.Desencriptar(id);
        /**************************/

        .....

        /********ENCRIPTAR********/
        //ClsEstadoRegistro Result = new ClsEstadoRegistro
        //{
        //    Detalle = Encrip.Encriptar(id)
        //};
        //Result.Detalle = Result.Detalle.Replace("/", "°");
        //Result.Detalle = Result.Detalle.Replace("+", "¬");
        //id = Result.Detalle;

        /*************************/

        return View(new ClsInteresado());
    }
```

Pero tampoco tuve resultados.

Yo pensaba que cuando el controlador recibe el dato desde el ActionLink, ese valor se mostraba en la URL, pero al parecer NO.

Por ultimo les adjunto un video que grabe del sistema en donde el se ve el id encriptado y luego se desencripta.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14q99P8R-SY5vdhlziXERlhy79v9Ixi-5

Comment: Si eliminas tu metodo desencriptar tu url -id seguira encriptado, y desencriptar paasalo a otra accion,

Comment: En realidad no estás encriptando, sólo estás ofuscando. Si realmente quieres encriptar deberías utilizar la librería que existe para tal fin: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Solo tengo 1 pregunta ¿por qué "encriptar la URL"?